# File Upload Path Error

Tags: android, image, upload

My app can run but it crashes when I try to upload a picture. The errors point on this lines:

> **String path=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));**

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();

    return path;
}
```

> **String path = getPath(filePath);**

```
public void uploadMultipart() {
        String path = getPath(filePath);

        try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            uploadReceiver.setDelegate(this);
            uploadReceiver.setUploadID(uploadId);

            APIV2 apiv2 = new APIV2();

            String url = apiv2.getChangeAvatarAPI();
            //Creating a multi part request
            new MultipartUploadRequest(getContext(), uploadId, url)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "file") //Adding file
                    .addParameter("type", "talent-avatar")
                    .addParameter("secret_key", apiv2.getSecretKey())
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+user.getToken())
                    .setMethod("POST")
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("ERROR UPLOAD: "+exc.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

> and this
>
> **uploadMultipart();**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        System.out.println("REQUEST CODE "+ requestCode);
        System.out.println("RESULT CODE "+ resultCode);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), filePath);
                profileImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                uploadMultipart();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && data.getExtras() != null ) {
            bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
            filePath = getImageUri(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), bitmap);

            System.out.println("CAMERA IMAGE PATH "+filePath.toString());
            profileImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            uploadMultipart();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whats the crash about ? add the error logs here .

Comment: Hi, here is the error

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: bizconnexion.com.graduan, PID: 17117
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/16 flg=0x1 }} to activity {bizconnexion.com.graduan/bizconnexion.com.graduan.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: its just like, i cant get the file path.

Comment: Do not add exception in comments , edit your question so that it will be readable .

Comment: You are #12346. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48962016/my-path-file-return-to-me-null?noredirect=1#comment84930153_48962016